# Hide a header section when it's loading within the Iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, iframe

I have a requirement where it has to be loaded a my asp.net mvc/angularjs app on another site.So I have to use `iframe` for that.

```
 <iframe width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="http://localhost:12534/home"></iframe>
```

sample page (index page) on my mvc site as shown below :

```
    @{
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

  //other page components
```

*_Layout.cshtml*

```
<body xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-cloak ng-controller="MainController">

    <header ng-class="{'no-shadow': page == 'home'}">
        <div class="container">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="/HowItWorks">How It Works</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

My Question : Could you tell me how can I hide the header section of the `_layout` page when it's loading within the `iframe` only ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `window == window.top` should do the trick. If the result is true then show/render the header. the JS object `window.top` references the top frame. If this is the same as the current window then your application runs not in an iframe

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I didn't get that.Can you put it as an answer with more details ?

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot.Could you put it as an answer ? Then I can close this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on startup check if the top window is same as the current window.
in case the top window is from another domain you might wrap the condition in a try-catch clause, because it could throw a permission exception if you try to access `window.top`.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function($window, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.isStandalone = $window == $window.top;
  });
```

in the HTML render the header on that condition

```
<div class="header ng-cloak" ng-if="isStandalone">[header]</div>
```

edit: [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/WKgz3RjXevLsu1jASbGp/preview)